# UI changes Portrait to Landscape when video player appears in Landscape on iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, ios11, landscape-portrait

**MyViewController** orientation is in **Portrait** mode.On that **MyViewController** i instantiate a **VideoViewController** after pressing on a button from **MyViewController**.In my **VideoViewController** class i played video in **landscape** mode using **AVPlayer**.Its work fine in all of the version of iOS except **iOS 11**. My problem is, when video appears in landscape mode than all the UI from MyViewController changes **Portrait** to **landscape** automatically only in **iOS 11**.

How could this possible ? I just Changed the orientation mode in landscape for  VideoViewController only but It changes the UI also from MyViewController class.

What will be the solution of my problem in **iOS 11** ? I have been searching for long time.Please help me out.